# Google DFP supplied script is listed as a parser-blocking, cross-origin script

Tags: parsing, cross-domain, google-dfp

I have the following standard code supplied by [Google DFP](https://www.doubleclickbygoogle.com/solutions/revenue-management/#error=no_adsense). Unfortunately it is being listed as a parser-blocking, cross-origin script because it is implemented using `document.write`

```
<script>
 (function() {
   var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
   var src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
   '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
   document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
 })();
</script>
```

I find this really odd because this is a standard DFP script from Google themselves. Is there an updated version that I should be using?

Comment: I changed the script to <script src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js"></script> still the problem is not resolved. The gpt.js uses 2 more document.write to write  2 more scripts. My Url is https://dnd-checker.talentpark.net/ Can someone find a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
(function () {
    var gads = document.createElement('script');
    gads.async = true;
    gads.type = 'text/javascript';
    var useSSL = 'https:' === document.location.protocol;
    gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
}());
```